# Bootstrap 5 how to make video size responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a very simple page in which have 2 columns. video and content i need to do width and height responsive something like image-fluid.

My code

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6">
        <div>
          <video muted="" autoplay="" loop=""
            src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/029113ae2cbbcf9493fe.mp4" type="video/mp4"
            width="950">
            <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/a667e994fc2f3e85de36.png" alt="Fast">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 align-self-center" >
        <h3>Fast</h3>
        <p>Flutter code compiles to ARM or Intel machine code as well as JavaScript, for fast performance on any device.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```css
.video_div{
  margin-left: -210px;
}
@media (max-width:1199px){
  .video_div{
    margin-left: -270px;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12">
        <div class="video_div">
          <video muted="" autoplay="" loop=""
            src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/029113ae2cbbcf9493fe.mp4" type="video/mp4"
            width="950">
            <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/a667e994fc2f3e85de36.png" alt="Fast">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 align-self-center" >
        <h3>Fast</h3>
        <p>Flutter code compiles to ARM or Intel machine code as well as JavaScript, for fast performance on any device.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Now its Responsive in all Screen,
send screenshot if any of issues is there with code. 
thank you !

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bootstrap 5, you can use the ratio helper :

> Use the ratio helper to manage the aspect ratios of external content like
> `<iframe>`s, `<embed>`s, `<video>`s, and `<object>`s. These helpers also can
> be used on any standard HTML child element (e.g., a  or ).
> Styles are applied from the parent .ratio class directly to the child.

source : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" title="YouTube video" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<video class="w-100" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/animation-intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

@*Note: w-100 is from Bootstrap 5.*@
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can Wrap any `video` tag in a parent element with `.embed-responsive` and an `aspect ratio`. The video tag can be given a `.embed-responsive-item` class as well

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
  <video class="embed-responsive-item" muted="" autoplay="" loop="" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/029113ae2cbbcf9493fe.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="950">
            <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/a667e994fc2f3e85de36.png" alt="Fast /">
   </video>
</div>
```

---

[Official Bootstrap Docs - embed](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/)